# NULL Reference Exception when generating DACPAC with particular Scalar UDF

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a SQL Server 2017 database with a particular UDF that is giving me an error when trying to export a dacpac either via SSMS or sqlpackage. VisualStudio also throws the error when working in ssdt. The function works, and no issues there. included here is a dumbed down version of the function that has the same issues. You can create an empty database, add the function, and dacpac extract will fail. I understand there are poor design choices here, but this is just an example of the script, that still reproduces the error.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testFunction]
(
    @string varchar(max)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Valid BIT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, ',') s
        OUTER APPLY (select LEN(s.value) AS l) AS l
    )
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    RETURN @Valid
END
```

It literally just takes a comma separated string, splits it, does an outer apply to generate a length(I know, stupid IRL, but demo).
However, when attempting to extract a dacpac it gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

If I change the select * to select s.value, or select 1, then voila, dacpac generates and visual studio doesn't crash.

Anyone have any ideas as to why the select * in the above code would cause the dacpac to fail? We're evaluating using ssdt for source control, but random stuff like the above doesn't give me good feelings about using it, when it apparently is doing more code validation than the sql engine itself.

Environments:

SQL Server 2017 Standard

VS 2019 community with SSDT installed

SQLPackage Build 15.0.4826.1

Comment: "It hurts when I do this" so the doctor said "don't do this." Obviously something in VS doesn't like `SELECT *` so use `SELECT 1` and call it a day? I always use `SELECT 1` inside `EXISTS()` or something else that makes it completely obvious this is not a data-retrieving query.

Comment: (It's possible that the reason it fails is that your function is impossible to create `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, but you'll probably have to talk to the team at Microsoft to know for sure, the "Object reference" error is not exactly the error message they intend to surface to users.)

Comment: Yeah, I typically use select 1, but this is an inherited database, and we're evaluating using SSDT and dacpacs for the source control and CI/CD goodies. Last time I looked into dacpacs was back on 2012, when it was still quite young.

Comment: I didn't think about the SCHEMABINDING thing. Though I don't see anything listed in the docs about that being required for dacpac compatibility.

Comment: I didn't see it documented either. It's just a guess. It could just as easily balk at anything that uses SELECT *, anything where it can't derive results using the describe DMFs, etc.

Comment: @BeardOfTriumph Wild guess, could you try the same with VS run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are affected by following bug in SSDT:
[SSDT failing to compile if STRING_SPLIT is used](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900770-ssdt-failing-to-compile-if-string-split-is-used)

It should be resolved few years ago, please check if you are using DACFX runtime 17.0.1 or newer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VS function Extract Data-tier Application, you can uncheck Verify Extraction. I had to do this when using a dacpac to restore an Azure SQL DB Managed Instance database that had views referencing another database to an on-premise server. Otherwise it would appear to create a valid multi-gigabyte dacpac that could not be deployed on-premise with the same error you are getting.